# How to get data from HTML page and put in a windows phone app?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, get

I'm trying to make a Windows phone app which takes data from an HTML page

HTML example

```
 <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderPrincipale_ListViewEventi_ctrl0_dataLabel" class="dataNotizia">27 dicembre 2013</span>
                    <br />
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderPrincipale_ListViewEventi_ctrl0_titoloLabel" class="titoloNotizia">FOCUS: ANCHE I VIP AL FREDDO COME I POVERI</span>
                    <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderPrincipale_ListViewEventi_ctrl0_LinkButton1" class="linkSMS" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPrincipale$ListViewEventi$ctrl0$LinkButton1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;sms_vedi.aspx?evento=FOCUS: ANCHE I VIP AL FREDDO COME I POVERI&amp;data=27/12/2013&quot;, false, true))">Vedi tutti gli SMS della puntata</a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
```

For example I want to show a list which shows the text in the class `titoloNotizia`. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to scrape a web page in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse HTML with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Comment: i've installed it, now?

Comment: now you have to parse the html string to find the corresponding class, extracting all matching entries as a List<T>

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from an HTML source, and show it as a software is a job of a Browser app.

Which requires you to get Network usage permission, which would load the data from the HTML source.

But if you're saying an offline (downloaded) HTML page, then you might need to edit the app as to read the HTML lines and show them as needed.

Still my bet would be a Web Browser!